# Proving Lorentz invariance of Maxwell equations

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, tensor-calculus

I've read somewhere that one does not need to prove Lorentz invariance of the Maxwell
equations 
$F_{\mu\nu,\sigma}+F_{\nu\sigma,\mu}+F_{\sigma\mu,\nu}=0$
because it is "manifestly Lorentz invariant" or "because they are tensor equations"? What is meant by that? I've read that this could mean that space and time are treated "on equal footing". How can this replace a mathematical proof?

Comment: You should learn what tensors are. To see why the equation is Lorentz invariant, you transform each component of $F$, since $F$ is a tensor (Lorentz invariant) the equation is invariant too. I guess this could be stated more rigourosly, but I don't know want you consider a mathematical proof. Maybe something like _Given a n-dimensional differentiable manifold M. Let F be..._

Comment: Really, if the Lagrangian is Lorentz invariant, the derived equations of motion will be too. Since the EM Lagrangian is given by $\mathcal{L}_{EM} = F^{\mu \nu}F_{\mu \nu}$, which is a Lorentz invariant scalar, you know the resulting equations of motion have to be Lorentz invariant.

Comment: Webb, the equation of the OP isn't derived from that Lagrangian however. That's the Bianchi identity and holds as soon as you say that your field strength $F$ is derived from a potential. $\mathcal{L}_{EM}$ gives you the other equation $\partial_{\mu}F^{\mu \nu} = 0$, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @jinawee: actually I deal all day long with the tensor product of the mathematicians, in commutative algebra. And in which sense is a tensor Lorentz invariant? you mean simply because one does not refer to the transformations in defining them?

Comment: To add a quick note: in physics, when we say an object is a tensor, we really mean it is a tensor with respect to the action of some group. But usually we leave the last bit out and are sloppy with our language. For example $F_{\mu \nu}$ is a (0,2) tensor with respect to the Lorentz group (or Poincaire in general), while something like say a Weyl spinor is a vector transforming under the fundamental representation of SU(2). a 3 vector like momentum is a vector under SO(3), while a 4 vector like the momentum 4-vector is a vector under the Lorentz group.

Comment: @nervxxx thanks for that, very useful to know. the cultural differences are sometimes a bit big

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't "replacing a mathematical proof". What the statements you are referring to mean is that in tensor notation, the proof is immediate, so that nothing needs to be written down. This is because if you have a tensor equation as above, in order to prove Lorentz invariance, do a Lorentz transformation and go to another set of coordinates $x^{\mu'}$. Then using the usual transformation laws we get that ${\partial_{\mu}} = \Lambda^{\mu'}_{\mu}\partial_{\mu'}$ and $F_{\mu\nu} = \Lambda^{\mu'}_{\mu}\Lambda^{\nu'}_{\nu}F_{\mu'\nu'} $, we can write the Maxwell equation in terms of the new coordinates to become

$\Lambda^{\mu'}_{\mu}\Lambda^{\nu'}_{\nu}\Lambda^{\sigma'}_{\sigma}(F_{\mu'\nu',\sigma'}+F_{\nu'\sigma',\mu'}+F_{\sigma'\mu',\nu'})=0.$

However, this can only hold if the thing inside the brackets is zero itself. Namely Maxwell's equation in the primed coordinate system also holds.

More succintly, what a "tensor equation" means is that there was nothing special about the coordinate system in which the equations were derived. You could have equally well chosen another system and derived the same equations. Thus invariance under coordinate change is immediate.

Comment: I see now. One should probably abolish coordinates altogether

Comment: Yes. You can write Maxwell's equations in terms of differential forms as well. This equation is simply $dF = 0$ in that notation.

Comment: Just canonical. I am surprised why the other more primitive versions still survive; after all it is survival of the fittest (in brit. english "fit" also means attractive ;))

Comment: Well firstly, it would be difficult to teach the most sophisticated version to people who are just starting out their undergraduate careers in Physics. Seeing how the electric and magnetic fields behave physically is also much clearer if you write them in terms of vector calculus notation.

Comment: It's also the case that in practice, computation in specific models is difficult and or impossible without coordinates.  Coordinates also lead to a lot of physical intuition (which is probably why, for example, Einstein thought in terms of coordinates when he was formulating GR, apart from perhaps modern differential geometry not being available, although I'm not sure about the history).

Comment: Einstein was quite unaware of most of differential geometry, as well as many other contemporary developments. He, for instance, struggled enormously with problems which would have been solved at once had he been aware of the Bianchi identities. This is all described in surprising detail in the excellent biography *Subtle is the Lord* by fellow physicist and physics historian Abraham Pais.